# What is the best way to generate keys in phpseclib?

Tags: cryptography, php

I am using phpseclib implementation AES and HMAC. But I dont know the best way to create random keys for these.
What is the best way to do?
Is there any built in function in phpseclib to create keys of the preferred length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the "Generating Keys" section of the [Encryption documentation](https://phpseclib.com/manual/06-Data-Encryption.md).

It suggests using the following code to generate a random key:

```
<?php
$key = \phpSec\Crypt\Rand::bytes(32);
```

For the sourceforge project, it appears that if you want a password-derived key, then you can use `->setPassword()` on the `Crypt_AES` object.  However, the only generation of random data that I could find is the generation of a random number.  That is done through [the `crypt_random` function](http://phpseclib.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/phpseclib/phpseclib/Crypt/Random.php?view=markup). I would suggest just taking the [necessary functions](https://github.com/phpsec/phpSec/blob/master/lib/phpSec/Crypt/Rand.php) out of the other phpSecLib.  As it is MIT-licensed, this shouldn't be a problem from a license point of view.

Comment: As it seems there are many php sec libraries. The one that I am talking about is http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: First, when people talk about phpseclib they're probably talking about the "sourceforge" version. First ten sites on Google are for that version anyway. Second, the "sourceforge" version has been hosted on github since last year: https://github.com/phpseclib . Check out http://www.ohloh.net/p/phpseclib/ vs. http://www.ohloh.net/p/phpsec/

Answer (score 1):

I woulds suggest using [crypt_random_string](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Crypt/Random.php). It's not in the 0.3.1 release but it is in the latest Git version.